# SQL Server DB Restricted Permissions

Tags: permissions, sql-server

is it possible to give someone permissions to a specific DB in SQL Server and he won't be able to **see** all the others DBs?
I don't want that the user will be even able to see the other DBs exists.
for example if I have this Dbs on my instance:

1. Accounts
2. Finance
3. Products

and for some specific user I want to give permissions only for the 'Accounts' DB, if he will log in to the instance (from MSSQL management studio for example) he won't be able to see that the instance have also Finance and Products DBs.

thanks ahead!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DougDeden I wanna know if that is even possible. the only thing I know is to give user permissions to a specific tables or schemas but he can still see that they are exist...

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (Mostly. The user in question will then have to be the database owner of any databases that you do want the user to see. And that is probably not desirable.) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341077/grant-a-user-to-view-single-database-deny-viewing-the-rest and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935018/hide-sql-database-from-management-studio/1430615#1430615 (SuperUser works best if the questions contain a description of what you've already tried, and what problems you've encountered. That's why I asked you.)